# Check if a List Element Exists in Dictionary Values

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list and a dictionary, and I need to check if elements of the list exist in the dictionary. If yes, I need to copy the key-value pair to a new dictionary, and discard the rest from the dictionary.

```
list0 = [
    -0.2385384148158066,
    -0.2307061452151448,
    -0.2150726345799602,
    -0.2138622652947372,
    -0.1098235264547504,
    -0.1072424768342444,
    -0.1037212327115436,
    -0.0966926943378552,
    -0.09614853460521154,
    9.353161396230564e-07
]
dict0 = {
    67: 1.440192237446893e-05,
    91: -0.1037212327115436,
    115: -0.2307061452151448,
    172: 0.0002879308975510175,
    242: 1.340170610273099e-05,
    266: -0.09614853460521154,
    290: -0.2138622652947372,
    347: 9.353161396230564e-07,
    417: 1.462739691486375e-05,
    441: -0.1072424768342444,
    465: -0.2385384148158066,
    513: 0.001208308075300354,
    606: -0.1098235264547504,
    630: -0.2442794187837403,
    677: 0.0007379497093922571,
    747: 1.336163063745514e-05,
    771: -0.0966926943378552,
    794: -0.2150726345799602
}
```

I tried iterating over the list and checking if the element is in `dict0.values()` and vice versa, but still couldn't figure out any way to access both key and value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension:

```
>>> {k: v for k, v in dict0.items() if v in list0}
{91: -0.1037212327115436, 115: -0.2307061452151448, 266: -0.09614853460521154, 290: -0.2138622652947372, 347: 9.353161396230564e-07, 441: -0.1072424768342444, 465: -0.2385384148158066, 606: -0.1098235264547504, 771: -0.0966926943378552, 794: -0.2150726345799602}
```

If your `list0` is very big, converting it to a `set` makes the above method faster:

```
>>> set0 = set(list0)
>>> {k: v for k, v in dict0.items() if v in set0}
```

Comment: what is the cost of converting to a set?

Comment: @Matiiss `O(n+m)` to convert the list to a set and then checking for `v in set0` m times, whereas first method is `O(n*m)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thats Pretty Simple to do:

This snippet may help:

```
new_dict={}
    for item in list0:
       for d in dict0:
          if(item==dict0[d]):
             new_dict[d]=item
```

Comment: Swapping the `for` loops and adding a `break` after a match is found will make this code faster. Also your indentation is off.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to figure out why didn't you get the answer by iteration. You've not pasted your code, so I'm giving the answer in iteration method only so that you can compare it with your code. The code would be:

```
list0 = [
    -0.2385384148158066,
    -0.2307061452151448,
    -0.2150726345799602,
    -0.2138622652947372,
    -0.1098235264547504,
    -0.1072424768342444,
    -0.1037212327115436,
    -0.0966926943378552,
    -0.09614853460521154,
    9.353161396230564e-07
]
dict0 = {
    67: 1.440192237446893e-05,
    91: -0.1037212327115436,
    115: -0.2307061452151448,
    172: 0.0002879308975510175,
    242: 1.340170610273099e-05,
    266: -0.09614853460521154,
    290: -0.2138622652947372,
    347: 9.353161396230564e-07,
    417: 1.462739691486375e-05,
    441: -0.1072424768342444,
    465: -0.2385384148158066,
    513: 0.001208308075300354,
    606: -0.1098235264547504,
    630: -0.2442794187837403,
    677: 0.0007379497093922571,
    747: 1.336163063745514e-05,
    771: -0.0966926943378552,
    794: -0.2150726345799602
}
new_dict={}
for i in dict0:
    if dict0[i] in list0:
        new_dict[i]=dict0[i]
print(new_dict)
```

Comment: you can get the values of a dictionary by using its `values` method

Comment: Yeah you can, an alternative 